# Can't align H1 tag to left with CSS?

Tags: css

Hi I seem to be having an issue trying to align an H1 tag to the left. I know it is something in my template.css file but I can't work out what.

[Have a look >](http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/smokinhot/index.php?page=shop.product_details&product_id=19&flypage=flypage_smokin.tpl&pop=0&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=5)

Should be easy for any CSS guru I hope ;)...

Comment: at least it's not a porno site :D

Comment: Could you please post the CSS and relevant HTML here.  I saw the page title and I don't want to open it at work.

Comment: I'm at work, you could have warned me about the nature of that site!  Anyhow, you may want to include a screenshot of the relevant part of the problem in this question, so that the question continues to be relevant in future.

Comment: I agree, the site is almost NSFW. Please add a comment to the question if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a developer tool like Firefox’ Firebug, Safari’s WebInspector or IE’s Developer Tools to inspect the document. Those will probably show your, that it’s the `.previous_page`’s bottom margin that causes a conflict with the top margin of the `h1`.

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, you where right it was a bottom margin on the previous page link causing the issue. many thanks indeed :)

Answer (score 3):

It's hitting that floated "Previous Page" link and wrapping around it. It's left-justified, but it just looks like it's centered because of where it hits that float.

Try:

```
h1 { clear: left }
```

Comment: thanks Tyson, it working already but that is a good trick to remember, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your h1 style to this:

```
#flypage h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, it was the previous page button affecting it but i did end up adding a top margin to the H1 tag, looks much better thanks :)